# How to perform a multiple groupby and transform count with a condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is an extension of the question here: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62845097/how-to-perform-a-groupby-and-transform-count-with-a-condition-in-pandas/62845108#62845108)

I am trying add an extra column to the grouby:

```
# Import pandas library 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# data
data = [['tom', 10,2,'c',100,'x'], ['tom',16 ,3,'a',100,'x'], ['tom', 22,2,'a',100,'x'],
        ['matt', 10,1,'c',100,'x'], ['matt', 15,5,'b',100,'x'], ['matt', 14,1,'b',100,'x']]

# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Attempts','Score','Category','Rating','Other'])
df['AttemptsbyRating'] = df.groupby(by=['Rating','Other'])['Attempts'].transform('count')
df
```

[image]

Then i try to add another column for the sum of rows that have a Score greater than 1 (which should equal 4):

```
df['scoregreaterthan1'] = df['Score'].gt(1).groupby(by=df[['Rating','Other']]).transform('sum')
```

But i am getting a

```
ValueError: Grouper for '<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>' not 1-dimensional
```

Any ideas? thanks very much!

Comment: is that possible to group by, by df? in the end line you have `groupby(by=df[['Rating','Other']])`

Comment: That's because you are trying to apply a groupby to a series ```df['Score'].gt(1)```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`df['Score'].gt(1)` is returning a boolean series rather than a dataframe. You need to return a dataframe first before you can groupby the relevant columns.

use:

```
df = df[df['Score'].gt(1)]
df['scoregreaterthan1'] = df.groupby(['Rating','Other'])['Score'].transform('count')
df
```

output:

```
    Name    Attempts    Score   Category    Rating  Other   AttemptsbyRating    scoregreaterthan1
0   tom     10          2       c           100     x       6                4
1   tom     16          3       a           100     x       6                4
2   tom     22          2       a           100     x       6                4
4   matt    15          5       b           100     x       6                4
```

If you want to keep the people who have a score that is not greater than one, then instead of this:

```
df = df[df['Score'].gt(1)]
df['scoregreaterthan1'] = df.groupby(['Rating','Other'])['Score'].transform('count')
```

do this:

```
df['scoregreaterthan1'] = df[df['Score'].gt(1)].groupby(['Rating','Other'])['Score'].transform('count')
df['scoregreaterthan1'] = df['scoregreaterthan1'].ffill().astype(int)
```

output 2:

```
    Name    Attempts    Score   Category    Rating  Other   AttemptsbyRating    scoregreaterthan1
0   tom     10  2   c   100 x   6   4
1   tom     16  3   a   100 x   6   4
2   tom     22  2   a   100 x   6   4
3   matt    10  1   c   100 x   6   4
4   matt    15  5   b   100 x   6   4
5   matt    14  1   b   100 x   6   4
```

Comment: Thanks @David. I would lke to keep the people with a score less than one also - but is there a way to show 4 in their row as opposed to `NaN`?

Comment: @SOK see updated code `.ffill()` fills the count over the nans and .astype(int) changes the dtype to an int.